# Getting duplicate array entries after parsing with regex

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I am using regex in my PHP script to check a page for Rapidshare links, and load them into an array.

My code:

```
if(preg_match_all('/http:\/\/rapidshare\.com\/files\/.*?\/[^\s]+/', $links[0], $links))
{
    print_r($links);
} else {
    die('Cannot find post links :(');
}
```

It finds the links correctly, and puts them into an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://rapidshare.com/files/320708377/file_name1.rar
            [1] => http://rapidshare.com/files/320708377/file_name1.rar
            [2] => http://rapidshare.com/files/333708133/file_name2.rar
            [3] => http://rapidshare.com/files/333708133/file_name2.rar
            [4] => http://rapidshare.com/files/330738827/file_name3.rar
            [5] => http://rapidshare.com/files/330738827/file_name3.rar
        )

)
```

As you can see, it enters two links into the array for each one. I have no clue why it's doing this but I suspect it's something to do with the regex.

Any help? Cheers. :)

Comment: Without seeing your data source, it's going to be hard to help.

Comment: Another Twilight New Moon sucker? :P

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record:

```
$array = array_unique($values);
```

It won't work for multi-dimensional arrays though.. so you would have to `for each` through the first array.

Comment: Not necessarily, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247950/how-to-remove-duplicated-2-dimension-array-in-php/1248189#1248189

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match_all`() will not magically duplicate URLs, they must be occurring 2 times each. Are you using the regex on a string of HTML? I suspect that if there's an `<a>` tag you're capturing both the `href` and the actual link text:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

*sigh* Happens because it's a hyperlink and it's grabbing the URL it loads to and the link text.

Answer (score 0):

[preg-match-all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)
Can subject and matches not using same variable name?

It is too confusing.

Also. give us the content of $links