# Efficient algorithm for detecting matches

Tags: php, algorithm, performance

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm for detecting equal values in an array of integers N size. It must return the indices of the matches.

Alas, I can't think of anything more clever then brute force with two loops.

Any help will be appreciated.
*Thanks!*

Comment: Can you give us an example of input and expected output? It would be easier for us to understand what you're after.

Comment: Also, you might want to think out your question and the requirements of the answer BEFORE you post the question. Last Minute Requirements just throw things off.

Comment: @Chacha102 you're right! i'm sorry!

Comment: I updated my answer with another option. It should be the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You could intersect the array. This finds all the values of array2 that are in array1

```
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "b" => "brown", "c" => "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("a" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result_array = array_intersect_assoc($array1, $array2);
print_r($result_array);
```

Would return

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
)
```

It returns an array with all of the keys and values of the matches. Basically you can provide an infinite number of arguments to the array_insert_assoc:

```
array_intersect_assoc($base_array, $arr1, $arr2 ...);
```

It will search `$base_array` for the values that are in all the subsequent arrays. That means that the key and value will be taken from the `$base_array`

You could also compare the keys by using:

```
array_intersect_keys($base_array, $arr1, $arr2, $arr3);
```

Comment: not sure, i mentioned that. but regardless, do you know if that can return the indexes of the matches found?

Comment: Yes. `array_intersect_assoc` will.

Answer (score 1):

These loops are O(N^2). Is N big? If so, can you sort the array O(NlogN), then scan it O(N)? ... or am I missing something?

Comment: And if you pair each element with its original array index and sort them together, you can recover the starting array indices for any elements that match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set to hold the recent values. For example,

```
results = empty list
set = empty set
foreach key, val in array:
   if val is not in set: add val to set
   else: add key to results
return results
```

Each look up of set is O(1), so this algo will results in O(n) instead of O(n^2) if nested-loop is used.

In case you want to keep track of multi-occurence like this array `1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1` you can use a hash table with key is the value and value (of the corresponding key in table) is the list of indices. The result for the given array will look lik {1:0, 5; 2: 1, 4; 3: 2, 3}.

```
results = empty hashtable
for each key, val in array:
    if val is not in results:
        results[val] = new list()
    results[val].append(key)
return results
```

Comment: Set lookups and insertions are generally O(log N).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?

```
$arr = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr)));
```

From the question: **[How to remove duplicated 2-dimension array in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247950/how-to-remove-duplicated-2-dimension-array-in-php/1248189#1248189)**

```
if ($arr !== array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $arr))))
{
    // found duplicates
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go through all the array again for each element. Only test an element with the subsequent element in the array:

```
$array = /* huge array */;
$size = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    for($j = $i + 1; $j < $size; $j++) // only test with the elements after $i
    {
        if($array[$i] == $array[$j])
            return true; // found a duplicate
    }
    return false; // found no duplicate
}
```

That's the most efficient way I can think of. Adapt it to your need as you will.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your arrays is reasonably static (that is you are comparing to the same array several times ) you could invert it.

That is set up another array which is keyed by value and returns the index into the real array.

```
$invert = array();
foreach ($cmptoarray as $ix => $ival) {
   $invert[$ival] = $ix;
}
```

Then you simply need an `if ( isset($invert[$compfrmarray[$i]) ) ....` to check the number.

Note: this is only worth doing if you compare against the same array several times!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an associative array mapping a value to its index:

```
foreach($array1 as $index => $value) {
    $aa[$value] = $index;
}

foreach($array2 as $index => $value) {
    if(isset($aa[$value])) {
        echo 'Duplicate:  .  Index 1:  '.$aa[$value].'  Index 2:  '.$index.'.';
    }
}
```